# error: Semantic Issue: Interface type cannot be statically allocated?

Tags: ios, ipad

What does `"error: Semantic Issue: Interface type cannot be statically allocated"` means ?

This is the wrong line:

```
UIViewController imageWithCaptionController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageWIthCaption" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
```

thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're probably missing '*' before imageWithCaptionController, your line should be

```
UIViewController *imageWithCaptionController = ...
```

Comment: This only explains how to fix the error. The OP asks what the error *means*. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8460375/172218) gives a more complete explanation.