# Interface type cannot be statically allocated?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface, compiler-errors, memory-management

I tried to put this in the header file of my view object:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIColor color;
```

to store the color that lines should be drawn with in this view.

Xcode gives me an error on this line:

> Interface type cannot be statically allocated

What does that mean, and what should I do?

EDIT:

I did add a *, and at the point of synthesis, it said:

ARC forbid synthesizing a property of  Objective C object with unspecified ownership or storage attribute?

Comment: The error message in your edit is a completely different issue. Please create a new question for that.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Your variable is for an object type, and as such must be declared as a pointer:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIColor * color;    // Note the asterisk
```

"Statically allocated" in this case would mean that the memory for that object was allocated at compile-time. All objects in Obj-C, however, are allocated at runtime and accessed through pointers.

"Interface type" is kind of an overly-technical term that's meaningful to the compiler, and not terribly important here. It means that `UIColor` represents the *interface* through which the compiler expects you to interact with the variable `color`. The actual type of the object pointed to may be different (as with a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html) like `NSString`).

Comment: why can I declare CGFloat statically then?

Comment: The size of an Objective-C object is unknown at compile time, right?

Comment: @William Sham CGFloat is not an Objective-C object.

Comment: @William: Because `CGFloat` is not an object, but a primitive.

Comment: @WTP: I can't remember. I think the size of a generic object (`struct objc_object`?) is known. With non-fragile base classes, I think that all objects are the same size, with another chunk of memory for ivars.

Comment: @WTP: Greg Parker [explains some of it](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html).

Comment: Of course, not quite _all_ objects are allocated at runtime. Constant NSStrings and Protocols are statically allocated. Blocks are weird.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you can only access Objective-C objects by reference through pointers, like this:

```
UIColor *color;
```

you can't have a "bare" object, like this:

```
UIColor color;
```

So the solution is to insert the asterisk in your code (which you probably meant to do, and the bug is just a typo).

Answer (score 6):

You need to declare a `UIColor` pointer like so and add retain/strong depending on whether you're using ARC or MRR:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *color;
```