# Interface type cannot be statically allocated when trying to concatenate strings

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL) saveSiteData  {

    //  validate all fields
    if(txtSiteID.text.length == 0 || txtSiteDesc.text.length == 0)  {
        [self Alert:@"Missing Site ID and/or Description" andData:@"Reqired fields"];
        return NO;
    }

    if(txtSTA.text.length == 0 || txtElev.text.length == 0)  {
        [self Alert:@"Missing Initial STA and/or Elevation" andData:@"Reqired fields"];        
        return NO;
    }

//    txtSiteDesc.text = txtSiteDesc.text.re  <----------  remove single quotes  TODO

    NSString selectCmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@", @"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SiteData WHERE SITE_ID = '",
                          txtSiteID.text, @"'"];
    return YES;
}
```

The error message I'm getting is: Interface type cannot be statically allocated.

Why? and how do I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interface type cannot be statically allocated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460340/interface-type-cannot-be-statically-allocated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString selectCmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@", @"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SiteData WHERE SITE_ID = '", txtSiteID.text, @"'"];
```

This is wrong. Any Objective-C object is a pointer. So you need an asterisk:

```
NSString *selectCmd = etc...
```

Comment: Seriously: you're abusing the format string. Why don't you simply write: stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SiteData WHERE SITE_ID = '%@'", txtSiteID.text];