# understanding the correct usage of pointers

Tags: objective-c, pointers, cocos2d-iphone

i'm declaring two property inside my interface
both of them should be pointers, but xcode gives me two different errors..

```
// myClass.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class CCNode;

@interface myClass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray myArray;
    CCNode myNode;
}
```

for the NSMutableArray:

```
Interface type cannot be statically allocated
```

for the CCNode:

```
Field has incomplete type 'CCNode'
```

in both cases, using pointers will solve the issue, but what's the difference between them?

with try-and-error approach, i found out that if i change `@class CCNode` to `#import "CCNode.h"` then it gives me the same error as the first line, but i'm definetly missing something for the correct understanding....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interface type cannot be statically allocated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460340/interface-type-cannot-be-statically-allocated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@class is a forward declaration of your class. It has incomplete type because the compiler doesn't know how large it is, whether it's a struct, an object, a builtin type, etc. When you import the header, the compiler has all the info it needs.

Comment: ok, that's clear.. thanks! so, keeping the forward definition (without importing the CCNode's header) and declaring the property as pointer (which removes the error) it's a good practice? or should change it?

Comment: It's good practice. Using the forward declaration of the class makes it so that if you change CCNode's header, it won't consider myClass's header to have changed as well. This limits the number of files that need to be re-compiled.

Answer (score 4):

> what's the difference between them?

The compiler knows the full definition of `NSMutableArray` because its header file is included via the `Foundation.h` header.  All it knows about `CCNode` is that it is an Objective-C class (thanks to the `@class`), not how big it is or anything else.

This is why including `CCNode.h` has the effect of changing the error, because the compiler now knows how big it is.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers need to be declared with a `*`, so your declarations should look like this:

```
@class CCNode;

@interface myClass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *myArray;
    CCNode *myNode;
}
```

Comment: i know that... i'm just wondering why it gives me different errors :)

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, you can't allocate an object on the stack, so the point is kind of moot.
Objective-C requires that all objects are dynamically allocated (i.e. on the heap). The error you're getting indicates that you're trying to create a CCNode object on the stack. All Objective Class objects are pointer types.

Statically allocated variables are used for primitive C types like int or double

int marks=100;