# objc call grandparent method from outside

Tags: objective-c, xcode, inheritance

I am recently developing an iphone app and I feel using inheritance makes the structure more sense and elegant.  However, I am struggling with how does inheritance work in objc.  The inheritance convention in Java does not seem work in here.

Circumstances:

It might be a bit complex but this looks the best way to describe the situation.  Let's say I have 2 classes, A and B. And they look like the following:

```
// Class A
@interface A: B
@end

@implementation A
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
    }
    return self;
}
@end

// Class B
@interface B: NSObject
@property A *littleA;

- (void)doSomething;
- (void)blabla;
@end

@implementation B
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        _littlea = [[A alloc] init]; // error: No known class method for selector 'alloc'
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)doSomething{
    NSLog(@"something");
}

- (void)blabla{
    [littleA doSomething]; // error: No visible @interface for 'A' declares the selector 'doSomething:'
}

@end
```

And outside of these classes, there is a class C.  In class B, I passed 'littleA' to Class C's method.  In that method, I did:

```
[littleA isEqual:NULL];// error: No visible @interface for 'A' declares the selector
```

I am utterly confused by these error messages.. Is this what the inheritance suppose to do?  In Java, A extends B, B extends C, then I can call from A:  a.b's method or a.c's method.

What did I do wrong? Anybody could explain the three error messages would be a great help!

Comment: Is this a copy-paste of your code? If so, don't you also have a warning about ["interface type cannot be statically allocated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460340/interface-type-cannot-be-statically-allocated/8460375#8460375)?

Comment: Hint: `@property A* littleA;` (note the pointer) Objective-C objects cannot be "statically" allocated. In other words, you can never have a variable that contains the entire object; you can only declare a variable that contains a reference to an object.

Comment: @Josh Caswell and James Bucanek thanks for pointing that out.  Unfortunately, it's my typo in the question..  I had the * for all my object properties.  I have fixed the code in the question.    But it's good to know the statically allocating objects.  I only know the difference between pointers and reference, not how are they allocated :)

Comment: You do not get an error on the very first line `@interface A: B`? Moreover, are you aware, that `A` is the subclass, not `B`?  Likely you should rename the classes in your sample code to `BaseClass` and `Subclass` to make it more readable. This code is not your real code and likely you forgot to import `A`.

Answer (score -1):

In class `B`, your declaration of property `littleA` is missing the asterisk (which in Objective-C indicates that the variable is an object).

`@property A *littleA;`

I think this will clear up the errors you've posted.

Comment: Sorry my typo.  There is a * sign in the code.  I have added it in the question.  But this seems not the cause of the errors...